# Keep line breaks with concatenate?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell that has line breaks. When I use the concatenate function on that cell, those line breaks are removed:

[image]

How can I keep the line breaks?

Edit: concatenate already works fine... I just didn't have wrap text enabled on the result cell...

Comment: Why use concatenate and not just `=A1` (and wrap text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered & ?

I tried this:

```
=A1&" "&B1
```

See
[image]

Then if you use "wrap text" it becomes:
[image]

Comment: @noClue See the edit, posted the first part then made sure of the second...

Comment: Haha... guess what? Concatenate already keeps the line breaks... I just had wrap text disabled there as well... I'm an idiot.